# Probability density of constructed variable

Tags: probability, integration, dirac-delta, line-integrals

first of all I have to say I'm a physicist and didn't have a single lecture on mathematical statistics or similar courses, so I'd like to apologize in advance for any inconvenience arising by notation.

My problem is basically of a very simple nature: Given a probability density $f(x,y)$ I have to find the probability density $p(z)$ of a variable $z(x,y)$.

Since my real problem is far too complicated to state here, let us for arguments sake assume that

\begin{align}
f(x,y) = \frac{3}{8} \sin(x)^3 \sin(y) \qquad z(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 \qquad x,y \in [0,\pi]
\end{align}

The first idea I had was a simple coordinate transformation
\begin{align}
\Phi : \begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix} \longrightarrow \begin{pmatrix}z \\ y\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
so that $p(z) = \int_Y f(x^{-1}(z),y) \left| \det J_{\Phi}\right| dy$. This doesn't seem to work at all...

My reasoning is this: Assuming $y=y_0=const.$ we can calculate $p(z,y_0) =f(x^{-1}(z),y_0) \left| \det J_{\Phi}\right| $, that is the distribution of $z$ along the line of $y_0$. Summing over all $y_0$ should then yield the distribution $p(z)$.

My second approach was more of a brute-force solution:

\begin{align}
p(z_0) &= \int_X \int_Y f(x,y) \delta(z_0-z(x,y)) dxdy \\
       &= \int_{z^{-1}(z_0)} \frac{f(x,y)}{\sqrt{\left|\nabla z(x,y)\right|}} d\sigma \\
&= \frac{3}{8}\int_{x^2 + y^2 = z_0} \frac{\sin(x)^3\sin(y)}{2 \sqrt{x^2+y^2}} dx dy
\end{align}

Evaluating this line-integral numerically yields the correct result (I've written a simple Monte-Carlo simulation to compare my solutions). Unfortunately I don't see how to solve this kind of integrals analytically.

I would be very happy if someone could shine some light on this problem for me.

Thanks in advance :)

*Edit:

Solution to the integral approach:
\begin{align}
p(z_0) &= \frac{3}{16} \int_{x^2+y^2 = z} \frac{\sin(x)^3\sin(y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} dx dy \\
&= \frac{3}{16} \left( \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin(\sqrt{z} \cos(\varphi)^3 \sin(\sqrt{z} \sin(\varphi) H(\pi^2-z) \mathrm{d}\varphi \right. \\
&+\left. \int_{\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{z-\pi^2}{\pi^2}}\right)}^{\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{z-\pi^2}{\pi^2}}\right)} \sin(\sqrt{z} \cos(\varphi)^3 \sin(\sqrt{z} \sin(\varphi) \left(1-H(\pi^2-z)\right) \mathrm{d}\varphi \right)
\end{align}

where $H$ is the Heaviside step function. A numerical integration yields (qualitatively) the correct distribution of z, see below for a comparison.

We have to distinguish between $0\le z  \le \pi^2$ and $z \ge \pi^2$ since $x,y\in [0,\pi]$. If we'd take the full integral over $\varphi$ from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ for all $z$ we would technically allow values for $x,y$ which are larger than $\pi$.

Our integration limits $\varphi_1 = \arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{z-\pi^2}{\pi^2}}\right)$ and $\varphi_2 = \frac{\pi}{2} - \varphi_1$ ensure that $x,y\in[0,\pi]$ always. To see that, imagine a square $[0,\pi]^2$ and start drawing circles of radii $\sqrt{z}$ around the origin. For $\sqrt{z}>\pi$ only a portion of the circle is contained in the square. A straightforward calculation then reveals the limits on $\varphi$.

Numerical Integration   : https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ln2o.jpg

Monte-Carlo Distribution: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRzH0.jpg

Comment: I think that maybe it makes sense to derive the CDF of $z(x,y)$ first (say, as a function of $z$) and then just take the derivative of the CDF.

Comment: My function $f(x,y)$ can be expressed as $\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial x \partial y}$ and my original approaches aimed towards transforming this into $\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial z \partial y}$  by simply applying the transformation theorem (applying the chain rule if you want so). This didn't seem to work out. I believe this $\sigma$ is what you're calling CDF?

Comment: No, by CDF I mean $$P_{X,Y}(X^2+Y^2\leq z)=\int_{X}\int_{Y: Y^2 \leq z-X^2}f(x,y)dx dy.$$ The pdf you are looking for will be the derivative of this functions with respect to $z$.

Comment: Often it is easier to analytically calculate such double integrals by moving from $x$ and $y$ to polar coordinates. Then it is easy to write such integrals as iterated integrals.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, I will have a look at your suggestion. For now I was able to solve the integral over the $\delta$-function and I will edit the initial post accordingly.